# Importing CSS Module styles from an external stylesheet in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, nuxt.js, css-modules

I'm wanting to import styles from my assets folder for my Nuxt assets folder.

For reference, my folder structure looks something like this:

```
assets/
  scss/
    example.scss
components/
  molecules/
    example.vue
```

In my example.scss, I have, for example:

```css
.red-text {
  color: red;
}
```

And in my Vue component, I have something like this:

```html
<template>
  <p>Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</template>
```

I want to give the scss "red-text" class to the paragraph `<p>` tag in the template (ideally with CSS Modules).

For instance:

```html
<template>
  <p :class="$style.red-text">Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</template>
```

If anyone could assist with being able to import it (I've had a look at the Nuxt documentation, and I've had a look at other StackOverflow questions, but to no avail), it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just guessing - could the problem be the dash (-) in class name? Did you try naming `redText` instead of `red-text`?

Comment: While that's probably a good idea, $style doesn't include it in the first place when it's imported via the next config

Comment: How do you import your style? Maybe $style doesn't include your css class for the same reason mentioned initially.

Comment: It's imported using Nuxts CSS array in the config file